# BASH: "Quoted out": Passing variable inside single quotes

Tags: bash, debian, parameter-passing

I need to run a script "myscript" automatically for cron. It needs some dbus functionality, so I had to create a wrapper script that calls myscript as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is a wrapper script
# Do some computation here
env `dbus-launch` sh -c 'trap "kill $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID" EXIT; /home/username/bin/myscript myarguments'
```

If i hardcode the value of 'myarguments' everything works as expected. If, however the wrapper is getting 'myarguments' from the command line, I'm at a loss as to how to pass it to myscript.

(Yes it *is* possible for me to write out the value to a file, and have myscript read it in, but a bash-only solution would be much appreciated)

Comment: What do you mean by *hardcode the value* and *getting from command line*?

Comment: As it stands, the arguments passed to myscript are myarguments, which i need to type into the script. If the wrapper script is called from cron, it will be called like this:
    $>/home/user/bin/wrapper newargs
The problem is that I cant think of any way to pass newargs to myscript, because sh -c requires a single quoted string - hence I cannot put any $variable in it. Apologies if that doesn't make anymore sense..

Answer (score 1):

You can use $1 as a reference to first argument the script receives.
If you have spaces in your 'myarguments' value you have to quote it.
You can find more details searching for 'bash arguments'.
You can pass multiple quoted strings as one parameter if you don not put any white space between the quoted strings.
Example:

```
env `dbus-launch` sh -c 'trap "kill $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID" EXIT; /home/username/bin/myscript '"$1"
```

Comment: Awesome. I assumed that sh -c needed a *single* quoted string, which apparently it does not, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is passing all parameters as one in the wrapper script quoting them:

```
$> wrapper-script.sh "param1 param2 param3"

#!/bin/bash
# this is a wrapper script
# Do some computation here
env `dbus-launch` sh -c 'trap "kill $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID" EXIT; /home/username/bin/myscript'"${@}"
```

In this way the `sh -c` parse them correctly (note the closing single quote before `"${@}"`)

Comment: Thanks, this works too. I have only one argument for now, though, so $1 is as good for me. Thanks

Comment: @kabZX: ok! I've seen the Vuk Vojta answer later, actually ``${@}`` is not needed here and $1 is enough (cause we use a single parameter anycase) but if you want to generalize and add more parameters to the ``sh -c`` this is the the way. Note that this works only with spaceless parameters (otherwise you have to separate parameters with some other char and play with ``$IFS``)